# Can I convert a string with json_encode back into readable html in a textarea?

Tags: php, html, json, laravel, wysiwyg

I have created a textarea with a wysywig text editor on it. The user would click into the textarea and start typing like any text editor. They would then save the form with that text and the data would then be saved into the database with `$data['description'] = json_encode($description_data);` this would save encoded string into the database.

The following is what I would get in the db column:

```
""<h1>test<\/h1>\r\n\r\n<p>paragraph<\/p>\r\n\r\n<p><u><em><strong>some text<\/strong><\/em><\/u><\/p>\r\n""
```

The reason this is in this format is because it is part of some json output as part of an api and the app needs the text to be converted in this format.

My main issue is this, when the admin goes to edit that data in the textarea the text is added back in as the data above which is expected as you can see below:

[image: the text editor with jsin in it]

This text needs to have none of this wrapping the content and be plain normal html in the textarea. Is this possible?

Here is the controller function below:

```
public function store(Offer $offer)
    {

        $offerId = $offer['id'];

        $data = Input::except('image','featured');
        //$featured_data = array( 'offer_date' => $data['offer_date'], 'starttime' => $data['offer_start_time'], 'endtime' => $data['offer_end_time'] );
        $description_data = $data['description'];
        $validation = Validator::make($data, Offer::$rules);


        if ($validation->fails()) {
            return redirect('offers')->with('message', $validation->errors());
        } else {
            $file = Input::file('image');
            $filename = date('Y-m-d-H')."-".$file->getClientOriginalName();

            $path = storage_path('app/uploads/' . $filename);
            Image::make($file->getRealPath())
              ->resize(600, 600)
              ->save($path);

              $data['image'] = 'storage/app/uploads/'.$filename;
              $data['description'] = json_encode($description_data);

            Offer::create( $data );
            return redirect('offers')->with('message', 'Offer added!');
        }

    }
```

And in the form I have got this:

```
<div style="clear: both;" class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('description', 'Offer Description:') !!}
    {!! Form::textarea('description', null, array('id'=>'editor1','class' => 'ckeditor form-control')) !!}
</div>
```

Hopefully this can be achieved.

Comment: I think you should save the data exactly as it has been entered by the user (possibly cleaned to remove script/style blocks, but that's a different issue), that is without json_encoding it. When you need to send it trough an API, json_encode it then, just before sending it (or with response()->json()).

Answer (score 0):

Just use json_decode when outputing. it do the opposite of json_encode.

Answer (score 0):

This is a json encoded string, although it's not valid solely.

Try this:

```
$var_str = '<h1>test<\/h1>\r\n\r\n<p>paragraph<\/p>\r\n\r\n<p><u><em><strong>some text<\/strong><\/em><\/u><\/p>\r\n';

$str_in = '{"s": "'. $var_str . '"}';

$sArr = json_decode($str_in, true);

$cleanString = $sArr['s'];
```

or the equivalent in javascript.

PHP fiddle here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/625c6ffd9d31215f8f73f6e02b5328e0fdf807e7

Comment: SoI get this returned `""{\"s\": \"\"<p>&quot;<\\\/p>\\r\\n\\r\\n<h1>test&lt;\\\\\\\/h1&gt;\\\\r\\\\n\\\\r\\\\n<\\\/h1>\\r\\n\\r\\n<p>paragraph&lt;\\\\\\\/p&gt;\\\\r\\\\n\\\\r\\\\n<\\\/p>\\r\\n\\r\\n<p><u><em><strong>some text&lt;\\\\\\\/strong&gt;&lt;\\\\\\\/em&gt;&lt;\\\\\\\/u&gt;&lt;\\\\\\\/p&gt;\\\\r\\\\n&quot;<\\\/strong><\\\/em><\\\/u><\\\/p>\\r\\n\"\"}""`

Comment: That fiddle is fine but this code needs to work inside a text field via the controller edit method in laravel